# How to get emails directly without storing in webmail inbox?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013, webmail, outlook-2016

I am facing problem regarding **Outlook** app. I have successfully connected webmail with outlook app, but when I delete email from Webmail then it also delete from **Outlook**. I don't want to delete from my ourlook app. It should keep it for my record.
One of my friend told me that he is getting mail directly from the sender to outlook app without storing a single mail on webmail server.

How can I customize settings to get my issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mail connection is IMAP, a delete will remove the mail everywhere.
If mail connection is POP3, it will not.